# I want to check if Ubuntu is using my NVIDIA graphics card

Tags: nvidia

After giving "nvidia-smi -a" command I got below output, Does this means Nvidia graphic not working? I am new to linux os

```
==============NVSMI LOG==============

Timestamp                           : Thu Jul 23 01:56:25 2015
Driver Version                      : 352.21

Attached GPUs                       : 1
GPU 0000:08:00.0
    Product Name                    : GeForce 820M
    Product Brand                   : GeForce
    Display Mode                    : N/A
    Display Active                  : N/A
    Persistence Mode                : Disabled
    Accounting Mode                 : N/A
    Accounting Mode Buffer Size     : N/A
    Driver Model
        Current                     : N/A
        Pending                     : N/A
    Serial Number                   : N/A
    GPU UUID                        : GPU-8d915dd4-46a3-5873-de52-c5af01f1faff
    Minor Number                    : 0
    VBIOS Version                   : 75.17.86.00.04
    MultiGPU Board                  : N/A
    Board ID                        : N/A
    Inforom Version
        Image Version               : N/A
        OEM Object                  : N/A
        ECC Object                  : N/A
        Power Management Object     : N/A
    GPU Operation Mode
        Current                     : N/A
        Pending                     : N/A
    PCI
        Bus                         : 0x08
        Device                      : 0x00
        Domain                      : 0x0000
        Device Id                   : 0x114010DE
        Bus Id                      : 0000:08:00.0
        Sub System Id               : 0x06521028
        GPU Link Info
            PCIe Generation
                Max                 : N/A
                Current             : N/A
            Link Width
                Max                 : N/A
                Current             : N/A
        Bridge Chip
            Type                    : N/A
            Firmware                : N/A
        Replays since reset         : N/A
        Tx Throughput               : N/A
        Rx Throughput               : N/A
    Fan Speed                       : N/A
    Performance State               : P8
    Clocks Throttle Reasons         : N/A
    FB Memory Usage
        Total                       : 2047 MiB
        Used                        : 161 MiB
        Free                        : 1886 MiB
    BAR1 Memory Usage
        Total                       : N/A
        Used                        : N/A
        Free                        : N/A
    Compute Mode                    : Default
    Utilization
        Gpu                         : N/A
        Memory                      : N/A
        Encoder                     : N/A
        Decoder                     : N/A
    Ecc Mode
        Current                     : N/A
        Pending                     : N/A
    ECC Errors
        Volatile
            Single Bit            
                Device Memory       : N/A
                Register File       : N/A
                L1 Cache            : N/A
                L2 Cache            : N/A
                Texture Memory      : N/A
                Total               : N/A
            Double Bit            
                Device Memory       : N/A
                Register File       : N/A
                L1 Cache            : N/A
                L2 Cache            : N/A
                Texture Memory      : N/A
                Total               : N/A
        Aggregate
            Single Bit            
                Device Memory       : N/A
                Register File       : N/A
                L1 Cache            : N/A
                L2 Cache            : N/A
                Texture Memory      : N/A
                Total               : N/A
            Double Bit            
                Device Memory       : N/A
                Register File       : N/A
                L1 Cache            : N/A
                L2 Cache            : N/A
                Texture Memory      : N/A
                Total               : N/A
    Retired Pages
        Single Bit ECC              : N/A
        Double Bit ECC              : N/A
        Pending                     : N/A
    Temperature
        GPU Current Temp            : 51 C
        GPU Shutdown Temp           : N/A
        GPU Slowdown Temp           : N/A
    Power Readings
        Power Management            : N/A
        Power Draw                  : N/A
        Power Limit                 : N/A
        Default Power Limit         : N/A
        Enforced Power Limit        : N/A
        Min Power Limit             : N/A
        Max Power Limit             : N/A
    Clocks
        Graphics                    : N/A
        SM                          : N/A
        Memory                      : N/A
    Applications Clocks
        Graphics                    : N/A
        Memory                      : N/A
    Default Applications Clocks
        Graphics                    : N/A
        Memory                      : N/A
    Max Clocks
        Graphics                    : N/A
        SM                          : N/A
        Memory                      : N/A
    Clock Policy
        Auto Boost                  : N/A
        Auto Boost Default          : N/A
    Processes                       : N/A
```

Comment: Did you install drivers for it?

Comment: I have only Nvidia in my computer and I have same almost same output ;-)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have installed proprietary drivers.

And also it looks like you have hybrid Intel+Nvidia graphics.

You can check which adapter is used by running in terminal

```
prime-select query
```

You can also check by

```
glxinfo | grep OpenGL
```

Comment: Output is "nvidia"

Comment: So it is Nvidia.

Comment: I got this @vaibhav-Inspiron-3542:~$ glxinfo | grep OpenGL
OpenGL vendor string: NVIDIA Corporation
OpenGL renderer string: GeForce 820M/PCIe/SSE2
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.3.0 NVIDIA 352.21
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.30 NVIDIA via Cg compiler
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 4.5.0 NVIDIA 352.21
OpenGL shading language version string: 4.50 NVIDIA
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL profile mask: (none)
OpenGL extensions:

Comment: Another confirmation that Nvidia is used. If you switch to Intel, you will have different outputs of both commands.